# Why xetex failed to output hyperref bookmarks with revtex4-1 class?

Tags: xetex, pdftex, hyperref, revtex

With the following example using `revtex4-1` class, `XeLaTeX` could not output PDF bookmarks featured by `hyperref`, but `pdfLaTeX` could.
Removing the option `reprint` solves this problem, but the two-column layout is needed.

What is the reason and how to fix it?

---

```
\documentclass[reprint]{revtex4-1}

\usepackage{amssymb,amsbsy,bm,amsmath}
\usepackage[bookmarks,bookmarksnumbered]{hyperref}

\begin{document}

\title{Title}

\author{Anonymous}

\begin{abstract}

This is an abstract.

\end{abstract}

\maketitle

\section{aaaa}

\section{bbbb}

\section{cccc}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

The `bookmark` package is recommended.

```latex
\documentclass[reprint]{revtex4-1}

\usepackage{amssymb,amsbsy,bm,amsmath}
\usepackage[bookmarks,bookmarksnumbered]{hyperref}
\usepackage{bookmark}

\begin{document}

\title{Title}

\author{Anonymous}

\begin{abstract}

This is an abstract.

\end{abstract}

\maketitle

\section{aaaa}

\section{bbbb}

\section{cccc}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks. But why the 'abstract' is not at the same level of other sections? Can the abstract's bookmark be removed?